# Issue with relative paths in PHP not working

Tags: php

I'm working on testing out a free helpdesk script on my site. I was able to get the script installed after some troubleshooting but it's still not working.

The error that I receive when I try to submit a new ticket is :

> Warning: require(./hesk_settings.inc.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or >directory in /home/onesourc/test/hesk/index.php on line 39
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required './hesk_settings.inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendFramework-1.11.6/library') in /home/onesourc/test/hesk/index.php on line 39

I do have hesk_settings.inc.php in the correct place and the relative paths should be working but they are not.

Here is a snippet of code out of the php file that's trying to find the relative path :

```
define('HESK_PATH','./');
require(HESK_PATH . 'hesk_settings.inc.php');
```

The code is coming from http://www.hesk.com. It's a straightforward install and I was able to get it up and running on my local xampp setup.

Could there be a setting on my Linux server that is causing this issue? A php.ini setting or something else? I thought of asking stackoverflow first since it's a php related question.

If you require anymore information let me know.
Thank you for your time!

---

**Update**

Not sure the best way to answer comments on here.
I was able to do "ls -la /home/onesourc/test/hesk/". There are too many subdirectory and files to add the asterisk at the end. It makes such a long list that I'm unsure how to retrieve it easily.

> ls -la /home/onesourc/test/hesk/

```
drwxr-xr-x  9 onesourc onesourc  4096 May 27 18:33 ./ 
drwxr-xr-x 22 onesourc onesourc  4096 May 27 00:01 ../ 
drwxr-xr-x  2 onesourc onesourc  4096 May 27 02:06 admin/ 
drwxrwxrwx  2 onesourc onesourc  4096 May 27 01:43 attachments/
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc  3191 May 27 02:06 change_status.php
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc  3444 May 27 02:06 download_attachment.php
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc     0 May 27 00:07 footer.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc   657 May 27 02:06 gd_test.php
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc     0 May 27 00:07 header.txt 
drwxr-xr-x  2 onesourc onesourc  4096 May 27 00:08 help_files/
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc  7394 May 27 02:06 hesk_javascript.js
-rw-rw-rw-  1 onesourc onesourc  5117 May 27 02:09 hesk_settings.inc.php
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc 10791 May 27 02:06 hesk_style.css 
drwxr-xr-x 3 onesourc onesourc  4096 May 27 00:04 img/ 
drwxr-xr-x  3 onesourc onesourc  4096 May 27 00:08 inc/
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc 32213 May 27 18:33 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc 23401 May 27 02:06 knowledgebase.php 
drwxr-xr-x  3 onesourc onesourc  4096 May 27 00:08 language/
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc  5843 May 27 02:06 print.php
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc  2246 May 27 02:06 print_sec_img.php
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc  3724 May 27 02:06 rate.php
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc 34057 May 27 02:06 readme.html
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc  6158 May 27 02:06 reply_ticket.php
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc  3273 May 27 02:06 secimg.inc.php
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc 12564 May 27 02:06 submit_ticket.php
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc  3270 May 27 02:06 suggest_articles.php
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc 18174 May 27 02:06 ticket.php 
drwxr-xr-x  2 onesourc onesourc  4096 May 27 02:13 tmp/
-rw-r--r--  1 onesourc onesourc 22181 May 27 02:06 TreeMenu.js
```

Comment: what does "ls -la /home/onesourc/test/hesk/* " show ?  what are the permissions ?

Comment: is there a '/home/onesourc/test/hesk/hesk_settings.inc.php'? that's the file PHP is not finding.

Answer (score 9):

PHP include paths are a bit of a tricky subject. In a nutshell, the `require` and `include` functions work from caller script, as well as the defined PHP include paths, which may not be the actual script itself. So take for example `test.php` which includes `libs/library.php`, which includes `functions/helpers/helper.php`:

**test.php**

```
require_once('libs/library.php');
```

**libs/library.php**

```
require_once('../functions/helpers/helper.php');
```

Now, looking at this code you'd expect `library.php`'s relative include to work. Unfortunately this is not the case. Actually, the require will be relative to **test.php**'s location, so you will get a fatal error in your include.

One way to solve this is by having an include file that lists absolute paths to various commonly used directories. For example:

**global.php**

```
define("APP_ROOT", "/home/user/site");
define("LIB_DIR", APP_ROOT . "/libs");
define("FUNCTION_DIR", APP_ROOT . "/functions");
```

Now since the paths are absolute, we won't have a problem including the files:

**test.php**

```
require_once('global.php');
require_once(LIB_DIR . '/library.php');
```

**library.php**

```
require_once(FUNCTION_DIR . '/helpers/helper.php');
```

Another alternative, though I think less preferred method, is to use `dirname(__FILE__)`, which gives you an absolute path to the current file, which you can then use for relative includes:

**library.php**

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../functions/helpers/helper.php');
```

This is not as clear as the constant names method shown above.

Comment: Thank you for your response! That will be super helpful for when I start writing my own scripts.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone was being kept up awake trying to solve this for me I wanted to post the solution I found before I went to bed.

After much searching about apache and php settings I finally came across information on the .htaccess file. For those of you who don't know (like me) what an .htaccess is here is the definition from the apache.org site:

> .htaccess files (or "distributed configuration files") provide a way to make configuration changes on a per-directory basis. A file, containing one or more configuration directives, is placed in a particular document directory, and the directives apply to that directory, and all subdirectories thereof.

In the parent directory from where my hesk script is located I had a .htaccess file that has these lines in it :

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^filename/([A-Za-z0-9_%\s\.-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/oneSOURCE\.html$ /functions/download2.php?file=$2&filename=$1&key=$3 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/userfiles/documents/"
      RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/functions/download2.php"
      RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/functions/databaseDump.php"
      RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/functions/queryResults.php"
      RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/functions/checkForDocs.php"
      RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/reports/"
      RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule \.(php)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule \.(html)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) - [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

I created a .htaccess file with "RewriteEngine off" in it and uploaded to the hesk directory. Now the relative paths from the original script are working just fine.

I apologize if this question and answer doesn't belong in stackoverflow. I initially thought the issue had to do with php and coding but it seems it had to do with the directory's apache configuration.

PS If anyone is curious on the route I took to find this solution feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: way to go. htaccess not my forte. just curious, don't need full explanation, but in nutshell, the htaccess prevented access to anything other than index.php?

Comment: @yitwail I don't believe so. I was still able to bring up various pages within the script. It's just when the script needed to access any other files through a relative path they didn't work.
I haven't taken the time to look up exactly what RewriteRule and RewriteCond are for and what these are doing in this case. Maybe when I get some free time I'll give it a look.
If anyone else is more knowledgeable about apache configuring feel free to chime in.